Does AI use lots of water?
According to Futurism:

Just how much resources are eaten up when you ask OpenAI's ChatGPT to write a simple 100-word email?
The answer may alarm you. The answer is about equivalent of a full bottle of water and enough power to light up 14 LED bulbs for one hour,

The electricity consumption is obvious, but the water?
My understanding is that water is pumped around the hot components, carrying heat away to a heat sink somewhere else. The water might be cooled and re-circulated, but if not, it's still just water, can't it be delivered back into the main water supply?
What actually happens to the water?

Depending on what the calculation includes, this might be manufacturing or simple loss of cooling liquid. For the record (I am only familiar with some data centres, not those running ChatGPT) most such machines don’t use pure tap water.

There's also the issue of where the water comes from. E.g. if it's pumped from a river and then dumped back into it, slightly warmer, it's hardly an "eaten up" resource.

How big is "a full bottle of water"? 3L, ¼L? And how much power does an LED bulb use? A floodlight uses a lot; a pixel on an OLED screen uses almost nothing. "14" seems far too precise to appear in such a general statement.

@RayButterworth Dumping back warm water (in significant quantities) doesn’t remove the water as a raw resource but impacts the ecosystem and what you can do with it. Trivially, you couldn’t just use the same water for cooling over and over again, for example.

How useful it would be if datacentres and AI machines and quantum computers could absorb CO2.

Some data centers use evaporative cooling. That definitely increases demand on water sources, even if it is returned to the atmosphere and will eventually rain down elsewhere.

@jpa in fact the linked article includes a summary of a discussion of evaporative cooling being a cause, but unfortunately in their summarizing they removed those two key words.

One thing I am wondering is if the water is literally consumed on command when a question is asked, or whether this represents an accounting proration of the amount of water necessary to keep the AI systems online divided by the number of queries actually made. If the second is true (which seems more likely) water is going to be consumed even if nobody asks a question.

@RobertColumbia Cooling needs definitely follow the power usage of the machines, and machine power consumption follows computational needs. Most data centers even put whole servers into standby mode if they are not currently needed (they have a strong economic incentive to conserve electricity).

@RobertColumbia You can check on most computers that running compute or graphics intensive tasks increases the cooling demand - the hardware of ChatGPT is fundamentally the same. Most compute hardware can idle at room temperature, the cooling is mostly for load.

Further reading: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Anu5E4jbnkI. Datacenters need cooling. Some use evaporative cooling, some closed loop. Power generation (nuclear, coal, gas) need cooling. Many uses cooling towers which uses water.

Estimates for AI water consumption are based on spikes in water consumption reported by tech companies who were developing AI, though none of them admitted what caused the increases. The numbers are old, however, dating from 2022, and the resulting estimates for total usage per query don't seem to cover anything other than the GPT-3 version of ChatGPT. AP News provides a solid account:

In its latest environmental report [2022], Microsoft disclosed that its global water consumption spiked 34% from 2021 to 2022 (to nearly 1.7 billion gallons, or more than 2,500 Olympic-sized swimming pools), a sharp increase compared to previous years that outside researchers tie to its AI research.
“It’s fair to say the majority of the growth is due to AI,” including “its heavy investment in generative AI and partnership with OpenAI,” said Shaolei Ren, a researcher at the University of California, Riverside who has been trying to calculate the environmental impact of generative AI products such as ChatGPT.
In a paper due to be published later this year [2023], Ren’s team estimates ChatGPT gulps up 500 milliliters of water (close to what’s in a 16-ounce water bottle) every time you ask it a series of between 5 to 50 prompts or questions. The range varies depending on where its servers are located and the season. The estimate includes indirect water usage that the companies don’t measure — such as to cool power plants that supply the data centers with electricity.

The referenced paper by Shaolei Ren is Making AI Less “Thirsty”: Uncovering and Addressing the Secret Water Footprint of AI Models on arXiv with code on GitHub (i.e., no peer review); I can't find any published version. Though Washington Post (which Futurist cited) says that's where the estimate for GPT-4 water consumption comes from (a query for a 100-word email "requires 519 milliliters of water,
a little more than 1 bottle", or 5 times as much as the high bound estimate for GPT-3), their source (Ren's paper) specifically says "Due to the limited public data available for GPT-4, we now present a case study to estimate GPT-3's operational water consumption footprint." All we can say about it is that water consumption for it must be higher.

It would be useful to know how much %-wise is that indirect use. I suspect it's the majority of it.

@Believeitornot... I think you're looking for table 1 in the linked paper. In most locations, most of the water used is "off site" but in some cases it's about equal or the reverse.

The futurism article cites this Washington Post article, which in turn states "A full methodology can be found in their paper “Making AI Less “Thirsty” [...]”".
The paper only seems to estimate for GPT-3 and gives 17ml of water for a page of content. It's possible the figure claimed in the articles (a full bottle of water for a 100-word email) is not yet published. To check the paper's methodology:
This paper uses OpenAI's own estimate of "0.4kWh electricity to generate 100 pages of content" and Microsoft's own figures for their datacenter Water Use Effectiveness - now averaging around 0.5 litres used for humidification/cooling per kWH. Multiplying 0.004kWh × 0.5 gives 2ml of water for a page of content, so the paper's estimate of 2.2ml of on-site water usage for the US average seems to check out.
The majority of the paper's reported water usage comes from off-site usage. To estimate this, the authors "use the regional electricity water intensity provided by [20 - WRI guidance] wherever applicable". Here, hydropower absolutely dominates both withdrawal ("sum of the water that is needed for turbine operation of the hydropower plant") and consumption ("evaporative losses from the reservoir").

So using figures from the paper and its sources, and assuming I haven't made a mistake, the breakdown of water usage for generating one page of content in the US looks something like:

While I can understand why WRI measured in this way when considering "dependence on water resources" and susceptibility to drought, I don't think it's reasonable to include unprocessed water, that would've just flowed into the ocean had the dam not been there, within the framing of "resources are eaten up" as the article does.
Given these figures, an estimate of 3ml of water per page of content generated appears more reasonable, including the water evaporated for cooling/humidifying and non-hydro power generation.

Hydro power doesn't consume the water, per se. It's placed in the flow path of the water and disturbs it briefly but then releases it in identical condition.
Thermal power plants, however (nuclear, coal, gas, biomass, MSW) are basically just giant boilers - they make power by converting water to steam then forcing it through a turbine. That process does materially impact the availability of that water supply, and so are likely the primary source of water consumption resulting from AI.

@WilliamWalkerIII I agree - in the figures used by the paper, hydropower is counted as having orders of magnitude higher withdrawal and consumption than other power sources, which I do not believe is reasonable when the figures are used for this purpose. Excluding hydro, it's about 3ml water total (on and off site) per page of content, which I believe would be a better estimate.

I wonder how much water is wasted every time there is a televised NFL game. Ignoring everything else, think of how much electricity is used by millions of televisions.

@RayButterworth Say, 20 million viewers × 3 hours × 100W average TV energy usage = 6000000kWH. Then, 6000000kWH × 3.142L/kWH (US average electricity water intensity used by the paper) = 18,852,000 litres

By the way, that 0.004 kilowatt-hours for an email is about 0.014 megajoules. Someone below mentioned rice: rice production, while not the most efficient, requires about 2.76 megajoules of energy input per kilogram under good conditions (Hossain et al., 2019). If one kilogram can feed a person for a day, and writing an email takes two minutes of that day, then it takes about 0.004 megajoules to let then write an email (assuming the cost of sending it is negligible). Of course, there are more efficient crops than rice.

Anyway, since food is essential, the reality is that writing an email should be nearly "free" relative to the human baseline. One cannot, or at least should not, just decide to stop eating in order to send more GPT-generated emails at the same energetic cost. Don't tell the robots how much the human baseline is, though.... But the real concern is not about sending one or two emails; it is about silly things like companies deciding to replace their mass form email to 5 million people with 5 million individually generated LLM responses. And if that seems absurd, just look at Google search now.

"Lots" is not a technical unit of comparison.
As such, what you consider to be 'lots' is subjective and dependent upon what benchmark you're comparing against. As observed in other answers: compared to a single pound of beef? No.
Compared to an email you wrote yourself? Maybe... how easy is writing for you?
Compared to simply retrieving and displaying an equivalent volume of text? Oh goodness yes, orders of magnitude more.
Water is almost never destroyed, it just changes phase
Water exists in a cycle. It condenses from vapor, falls as rain, flows as water, evaporates back into vapor - rinse and repeat.  As such it is not 'consumed' except by electrolysis - but when you then re-oxidize the hydrogen you've brought that same mass back to the water cycle again.
So it's important to define what we mean by 'consumes water.'
Water vapor is of zero value when you're thirsty, and you'll die of thirst if you try waiting around for it to naturally condense into rain you plan to drink.  As such, the stock of available liquid water that can be accessed by the drinking water distribution infrastructure is the resource of concern.
Water cooling is a popular thermal management strategy
Water has excellent thermal properties because of its high mass, ease of manipulation, lack of either basic or acidic Ph, ubiquity in most environs, and familiarity.  Other coolants can outperform but they are comparatively complicated to synthesize - and most require water as a base ingredient anyway.
Just adding heat to water doesn't contaminate it ceteris paribus - but ceteris are almost never paribus. Thermal pollution is a concern wherever microorganisms might bloom, or local flora or fauna have their behaviors disrupted. Nothing new about this, just a known form of pollution from these systems.
Cooling schemes that use water come in two flavors: once-through, and recirculating (recirc).
Once-through takes water at ambient temperature from outside the system, and uses it as a liquid heatsink. Once invested with waste heat, it's discharged back to the environment - this creates the most thermal pollution, but greatly simplifies systems that produce vast quantities of heat.  These systems also require tremendous mass-flow and generally must be located near large bodies of open water. The common exemplar here is a coal-fired powerplant.
Recirc systems take the hot water and push it through a heat pump or other secondary heatsink to bring the original water back down to base temperature and then send it around again. Once charged with the original supply of water they only need to draw sufficient water to replace evaporative losses (which are much higher than once-through systems, but often orders of magnitude lower than the raw draw rate of once-through).  Datacenters tend to be this type and many power plants are working in this way now, as well.
Electrical power production induces water demand as well.
Current electrical power comes from one of three sources:

A minority of electrical power comes from band-gap schemes (photo- and thermal-voltaic - what most people think of as 'solar');
A larger minority of electrical power comes from mechanical drive systems (wind, wave, hydroelectric, and tidal power);
The overwhelming majority comes from thermal generation (coal, nuclear, gas, MSW, biomass, concentrating solar).

Thermal generation is a simple process: Get a hot thing, boil a ludicrous quantity of water into steam, force said steam through a turbine.  Steam is not a useful form of water, and so to the extent that this process water is not perfectly condensed back into liquid for re-use, it is lost to the relevant system.
This can range from the hundreds of gallons per MWh to tens of thousands of gallons per MWh depending on the specifics of how it's set up.
Water needed for this process comes from somewhere, and if that somewhere is already scarce then you've got a resource constraint.
Water consumption of AI systems is higher than other use cases.
An inescapable consequence of AI is that it requires processor time. Thermodynamics tells us that this will invariably require the consumption of electrical power and produce waste heat.  There is no escaping either need, though technological advancement can asymptotically move them towards zero.
Where I need more cooling service, I suffer more evaporative losses.
Where I consume more electrical power, I suffer more evaporative losses.
So anything that requires more electrical energy will, of necessity, also require the measurable diversion of more water.  Period.
The use phase water isn't the end of the story, either.
Much of the analysis focuses on the water consumed by marginal use of AI (that is to say, the scope 1 and 2 water demand induced by a query).  But it is not unreasonable to insist that the development phase be included as a cost.
AI models require extensive, very power hungry (and therefore water hungry) training periods measured in months where no valuable content is being generated.  From an economics perspective, these costs should be amortized over the useful life of the AI model so as to be converted into an appropriate 'per unit' cost.  We don't have that data until the AI model reaches the end of its useful life.  All that can be said with certainty, however, is that any given AI model consumes more power and water than the marginal costs reflect. We can estimate how much more if we make assumptions about how many queries we'll get out of the thing, but none of that is certain.
TL;DR
AI processes consume more power and therefore more water than comparative processes. Whether this is "lots" is a function of what value you place on the product of those processes.  If you believe the product to be valuable, the price in terms of resource consumption will likely seem fair.  If you believe the product to be a waste, you will certainly object to the higher costs.
Comparing to other products in the economy (e.g. beef) is only possible once we have made valuation determinations between "100 words of text I didn't have to write myself" and "enough food for me to live another day."
YMMV.

"Water consumption of AI systems is higher than other use cases." What other usecases? Of course it’s trivially higher than not doing anything, but surely there are usecases that also need energy - how does it compare to related tasks? Say I type an email by myself, how much power is consumed because I don’t write as quickly as GenAI? How much power is consumed if I need a spellchecker?

@MisterMiyagi There are too many assumptions that would need to be defined to answer your specific inquiry, which is why I am forced to speak generally.

@WilliamWalkerlll Well, I am pretty sure that "Water consumption of AI systems is higher than other use cases." in general is wrong. Surely AI systems don’t generally use more energy than other use cases, i.e. more than most if not all of them.

@MisterMiyagi - At the moment, "generally higher than most other computing tasks" would be accurate, and even "generally higher than most human solutions." This may change, of course.

@Obie2.0 I don’t see why that would necessarily be the case. The TPUs used for GenAI are rather efficient for what they do; many human built programs are very badly optimised and use inefficient general purpose CPUs. Sure, an entire GenAI compute centre is going to pull quite some power, but so do compute centres for other tasks. The HPC top 500 is full of GPU/TPU beasts.

@MisterMiyagi - For what they do. Sure, they are efficient at training and running models with 2 trillion floating point numbers; the thing is, 90% of what computers do can (and sometimes does) work by manipulating the equivalent of a 1 KB text file. The efficiency doesn't matter when you are talking about orders of magnitude more floating-point calculations. By some estimates, GPT-3 used around 10 times as much energy as a Google search (before Google started sticking obligatory LLM outputs in its search results, at least), and Google Search was already less efficient than necessary.

That was with a model that was smaller and presumably less intensive to run than the current ones. So yeah, I think that short of things like gaming, not much is going to need more power. And that's without factoring in training costs.

@Obie2.0 Sorry, I am looking for actual sources, not anecdotes. I do work in a compute centre, with close ties to about 300 more and looser ties to other compute infrastructure - so I do have ample anecdotes already. But they are just that. I am here on Sceptics to get sources instead and substantiated claims. Is "90% of what computers can do" just hyperbole, or an estimate (based on what?) or is there an actual source? At the end of the day, just as for water, it is relevant what volume metric the "90%" or "not much [more tasks]" and other comparisons actually use.

@MisterMiyagi For any rational actor reviewing the output of ChatGPT to compose an email (since otherwise you have agent/principal issues that immediately arise) you have scenario A which consists of "Think about an email, press some keys, hit send." and scenario B which includes all of the above, PLUS the required costs for ChatGPT to compose the email, the only scenario where B<A is one where someone is basically unable to effectively compose an email (which also renders them unable to effectively vet the product in all but a few corner cases).
Thermodynamics doesn't negotiate.

@WilliamWalkerIII The usual usecase for writing via GenAI is preparing a draft and feeding that to the AI. It is not writing completely and feeding that to GenAI. So using GenAI is not "usual costs plus GenAI" but "reduced costs plus GenAI", which isn’t trivially comparable to "usual costs". Yes, GenAI may well work out to be more costly but it is not a self-evident relation.

@MisterMiyagi That is not the use case described in the article linked in the OP.   From the OP: "Just how much resources are eaten up when you ask OpenAI's ChatGPT to write a simple 100-word email?"  The verb is 'to write' not 'to edit' nor 'to improve upon.'

@WilliamWalkerIII That usecase is even further away from the one you mentioned of writing it yourself regularly plus GenAI - it would be just GenAI. Anyway, GenAI needs some input on what the email should be about, i.e. a (very, very rough) draft.

No.

Paper (Li et al, 2023, also forthcoming in Communications of the ACM, 2024).
Article covering this paper by The Washington Post: 2024-09-18, non-paywalled.

The article says that a 100-word email requires 519 milliliters of water. Is that "lots of water"?
The same article states:

It takes about 6,992 liters of water to produce 1 pound of beef.


It takes about 4,956 liters of water to produce 1 pound of rice.

So, producing 1 pound of beef uses as much water as generating 6992/.519 ≈ 13472 emails. And, producing 1 pound of rice uses as much water as generating 4956/.519 ≈ 9549 emails.
So if an email uses up "lots of water", then producing 1 pound of beef or rice uses up about 10000 × "lots of water".
So, if you're not willing to admit that whenever you consume 1 pound of beef or rice, you use up 10000 × "lots of water", then you should also not be willing to say that an email uses up "lots of water".
(The problem with this question is the very vague phrase "lots of water".)

Data centers do reuse water. But very importantly, there's evaporation and hence water loss. Li et al (2024):

For example, training GPT-3 in Microsoft’s state-of-the-art U.S. data centers can directly evaporate 700,000 liters of clean freshwater

Also, Zhang (2024):

Replacement becomes necessary either due to the risk of scale formation or when the water’s conductivity reaches excessively high levels.


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Yes, because it would involve huge amounts of power. Experts predict AI data centers will use 5-10 times more power per bit rate of information flow.
Microsoft is in such a pinch for new data centers that they are in talks towards recommissioning the Three Mile Island nuclear plant whose working reactor produces 800 Megawatts.
See PC Gamer for more information.
Cooling data centers uses huge amounts of water. AI's projected water usage could hit 6.6 billion m³ by 2027 according to an article by Forbes.

This seems like only the first step of an argument. Why do huge amounts of power equal using lots of water? What does "bit rate of information flow" even mean, and compared to what is the power demand higher?

(as an AI skeptic) This seems to be based on companies investing on AI becoming very widespread and widely demanded, not on individual demand right now. It is possible that this is misguided and these datacenters won't be used mainly for AI workloads, if at all. It is also possible that we'll integrate AI into everything, and use the type of system in GPT O1 where a large number of tokens is generated to "think" about something before generating a shorter answer, then while per-token will perhaps be not that high (as stated in other answers), the total consumption will be high.
